# Migrating asp.net application containing classic asp pages as well as aspx pages from 1.1 framework to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, frameworks, migration

I have an application in dot.net framework 1.1 with some classic asp pages as well as .aspx pages.

I have to migrate this application to framework 4.0 keeping the asp pages as it is.Will this cause any problem during migration of the application.If so, what kind of issues are likely to appear.

Secondly, if  i do decide to convert those classic asp pages to .aspx pages than what do i have to do.Kindly guide me on the following issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic ASP pages will cause no problem to any .NET code - they simply are not present.

To convert them - there is no magic. You just have to find out what they do, then do the same thing in ASP.NET. Do not make a simple one to one conversion, instead take advantage of things like server controls.

Comment: Thanks.One more problem is that these classic asp pages are one folder above the folder containing the .sln file.So when i open the project these pages are of course not loaded.How can i load them or rather navigate to these pages when i browse the application on my local host.I wonder how these pages are working for this application.I am new to asp.net so i am not sure if my question is correctly formed.kindly guide

Comment: These files were not developed as part of a .sln. They may have been developed in "Visual Interdev", a predecessor of Visual Studio, so there may be some sort of project file describing them, but Visual Studio won't understand it. The deployment of these files is probably a simple COPY, so it won't matter whether they are part of the solution or not.